# What is the cause of "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in matmul ret = a @ b" when using sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I encountered RuntimeWarning when using `Ridge().fit(X_train, y_train)` on a dataset where `X_train.shape = (9440, 1900)`

```
/Users/username/micromamba/envs/data-science/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py:189: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in matmul
  ret = a @ b
```

When I reduce the size of dataset `X_train.shape = (1000, 1900)` the RuntimeWarning goes away.

What might be causing this warning and how can I avoid it? I made sure there are no np.nan, np.inf, and -np.inf.

Comment: Is there an NaN value anywhere in the X_train?

Comment: @NickODell. No there is none.

Comment: Possibly related to [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13173)

Comment: Have you tried other subarrays of X? Could there be an invalid entry at a higher index that is sliced away in your second test?

Comment: @Daraan - I checked for np.nan, np.inf, and -np.inf. Should I check for something else too?

Comment: I am wondering if for the second test you just remove the other 8840 samples. And thought maybe it would be interesting to check these, i.e. does it work if you split your data into 10 subsets and fit each of them, or is it a problem that appears only when you use >N samples?

Comment: I should add that there isn't enough code to reproduce the problem, and without a sample of the data it to diagnose the issue can only be guessworks.

Comment: This error occurs on some environments with perfectly valid data. Try on Colab and see if the error still occurs (see my answer).

Comment: @arjan-hada I have narrowed the error scope and helped to escalate the issue to the library maintainers, is there anything else that SO can help you with?

Answer (score 5):

This error is somewhat known, and is sadly **architecture / environment dependent**. This is a purely matrix op issue in numpy. I reproduced it in my Colab with the following code:

```py
# warning under numpy==1.25, OK under numpy==1.22.4
M = np.random.random((30000, 270)) # on Colab
M.T @ M
```

and @Stef tested the breaking numpy version.

See [this recent GitHub discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24067) under `numpy`, where I contributed this breaking example.

I created [this Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/maciejskorski/943dcdc214f1490e5e7046230a23bf16/numpy_matmul_bug.ipynb) to help root-causing the issue (works fine under `numpy==1.22.4` which is Colab's choice). Try your training under Colab (you can upload your data).

Overall my suggestion would be to downgrade the numpy version or wait for a fix from the maintainers.

Comment: the Colab notebook gives the same warning with numpy 1.25.0. As stated by the OP of the linked github issue this warning doesn't show up with earlier versions of numpy.